# Realm.io can't get examples to work

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm failing to get started with Realm.io, I've tried it in my own project aswell as with the IntroExample.

When i try to look up something, i get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mutable method call during read transaction.

When i try to store something, i get:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated proxy
>   class

I seem to have a fundamental flaw somewhere.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lorem.ipsum"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.+'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.71.0'
}
```

Comment: Without more information it is hard to say. What do you have in you libs folder? Also you seem to be missing a repositories definition with jcenter(), unless you have it configured in another file?

Comment: Can you provide the output of:

`./gradlew assemble`

Comment: @ChristianMelchior i have nothing in my libs folder. jcenter() is defined it the parents build.gradle file.

Comment: @Emanuelez http://pastie.org/private/m0amraxotb29js2bgppqwg

Comment: @darken I think I need to see some of the code you're trying to run

Comment: @Emanuelez An empty Android Studio project, that should just store an item or retreive one, neither works.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2650713/Realmtest1.zip Thanks for the help (You are from Realm.io team, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26294208/1251958 and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26326314/1251958 leads to success.

After adding the `@RealmClass` annotation @Philluxx metioned, i got errors in AndroidStudio pointing out the required syntax as mentioned by @ChristianMelchior

Note: You will probably have to clear the app data as neglecting to do either seems to lead to a corrupted database that leads to subsequent crashes.

Answer (score 8):

Make a `@RealmClass` annotation to your model class. I struggled with the same problem and went a bit deeper in the proxy class generation of Realm. Only classes with the @RealmClass annotation are generated.

```
@RealmClass
public class Category extends RealmObject {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks after adding the annotation i got errors pointing out the not confirming syntax as mentioned by others.

Comment: Still proxy classes are not being generating, what might be the reason?

Answer (score 5):

I tried to run your example code and got a lot of exceptions regarding your model class. It looks like your getters and setters have been renamed from the default, which currently breaks the annotation processor.

I tried to change the model class to:

```
public class DataItem extends RealmObject {
    private String uuid;
    private String content;
    private boolean bool;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public boolean isBool() {
        return bool;
    }

    public void setBool(boolean bool) {
        this.bool = bool;
    }
}
```

which seemed to work.

Comment: If it only takes specificly named getters and setters (which completely depend on IDE+config) and i can not add additional logic to the getters and setters, what is the advantage here? Why not just make a class with public fields and get rid of an extra layer that can break.

Comment: Currently it is due to the fact that Realm underneath hooks the getters/setters directly to the data in the database. Take a look at the *RealmProxy classes for more details. But yes, if a lot of people depend on the code templates to generate setters/getters, it might be worth it to rethink that approach.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior, in my case Proxy classes are not being generating, i have annotated the class with `@RealmClass` also i have tried using `JDK 1.8`, clean/build and restarting the Android Studio and system.

Answer (score 1):

Emanuele from Realm here.

I took a look at the example project you posted in the comments and the only problem I found was in the naming of the getters and setters.
We surely need to document this better but to easily get a predictable behavior you should let the IDE autogenerate the getters and setters for you. One note about booleans: it looks that if you have a boolean callaed `isValid` Android Studio will generate accessors named `isValid()` and `setValid()`. I'm not sure how Eclipse behaves in the same scenario. Anyway, in the annotation processor we generate something like `isIsValid()` and `setIsValid()` which is of course ugly and will be fixed soon. Anyway, if you name your boolean simply `valid` everything will work fine.

Comment: The getters and setters are actually generated by Android studio. If you are refering to the missing "m", that is because you can specify a naming prefix in the code generation templates.

Comment: @Emanuelez, I have just downloaded the latest version of Realm for Android, imported the intro example to the Android Studio (v0.8.6) and run it. The app crashes on launch with "Could not find the generated proxy class" exception on the line `Person person = realm.createObject(Person.class);`