# Cannot find io/realm/RealmProxy

Tags: android, realm

I have a problem similiar to [Realm.io can't get examples to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272382/realm-io-cant-get-examples-to-work). 
I tried the fix that was written there, but it still doesn't work.

I created two Realmclasses inside my AndroidApp for my Data.

Class one is called "Fahrt":

```
@RealmClass
public class Fahrt extends RealmObject {
private String fahrtname;
private String fahrtzeitstempel;
private String fahrtfahrzeug;
private RealmList<Data> listData;

public String getFahrtname() {
    return fahrtname;
}

public void setFahrtname(String fahrtname) {
    this.fahrtname = fahrtname;
}

public String getFahrtzeitstempel() {
    return fahrtzeitstempel;
}

public void setFahrtzeitstempel(String fahrtzeitstempel) {
    this.fahrtzeitstempel = fahrtzeitstempel;
}

public String getFahrtfahrzeug() {
    return fahrtfahrzeug;
}

public void setFahrtfahrzeug(String fahrtfahrzeug) {
    this.fahrtfahrzeug = fahrtfahrzeug;
}

public RealmList<Data> getListData() {
    return listData;
}

public void setListData(RealmList<Data> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
}
}
```

Class two is called "Data":

```
@RealmClass
public class Data extends RealmObject {
private String zeitstempel;
private String header;
private String canid;
private String data;

public String getZeitstempel() {
    return zeitstempel;
}

public void setZeitstempel(String zeitstempel) {
    this.zeitstempel = zeitstempel;
}

public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public void setHeader(String header) {
    this.header = header;
}

public String getCanid() {
    return canid;
}

public void setCanid(String canid) {
    this.canid = canid;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

I tried to store some data in this way.

```
//global declarations
private static String fahrtname;
private Realm realm;
private Fahrt aktuellefahrt;
private Data addData;
private static StringBuilder sb;
private String datensatz_string;
....
realm = Realm.getInstance(mContext);
//myPersistMethod
private void persist(byte[] message)
{
    realm.beginTransaction();
    aktuellefahrt = realm.where(Fahrt.class).equalTo("fahrtname", fahrtname).findFirst();
    if(aktuellefahrt == null)
    {
        aktuellefahrt = realm.createObject(Fahrt.class);
        aktuellefahrt.setFahrtname(fahrtname);
        aktuellefahrt.setFahrtzeitstempel(fahrtname);
        aktuellefahrt.setFahrtfahrzeug("testFahrzeug");
    }
    RealmList<Data> realmListData = aktuellefahrt.getRealmListData();
    if(realmListData == null)
    {
        realmListData = new RealmList<>();
    }
    datensatz_string = new String(toBinary(message));

    addData = realm.createObject(Data.class);
    addData.setZeitstempel((datensatz_string.substring(0,16)));
    addData.setHeader(datensatz_string.substring(16, 24));

    addData.setCanid((datensatz_string.substring(24, 56)));
    addData.setData((datensatz_string.substring(56)));
    aktuellefahrt.getRealmListData().add(addData);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
...
```

I allways get the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
>   cannot find io/realm/DataRealmProxy: io.realm.DataRealmProxy found in io/realm/DataRealmProxy.class

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What does your gradle build files look like? Are they configured as described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Comment: Yes. I will post my gradle file at the evening.

Comment: this is my build.gradle of the project
`// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
`

Comment: The other build gradle is to long for a comment. But there the second line is
`apply plugin: 'realm-android'`

Comment: It sounds like it should work. You can also see how it is done by our examples: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/build.gradle and https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/introExample/build.gradle ... If you have the same and it is still not working please create an GitHub issue so we can take a closer look.

Comment: very interesting. I created a new project, only for testing realm db. And this works. But inside my App, it doesn't work. Why

Comment: Try cleaning your build folder and gradle folder. It might be a faulty cache problem.

Comment: How can I do this?  Build-> clean Project?

Comment: Yes, or manually deleting `build` and `.gradle` folders.

Comment: It Still doesn't work. Still the same error.  `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
> cannot find io/realm/DataRealmProxy: io.realm.DataRealmProxy found in io/realm/DataRealmProxy.class` 
How can I create an Github issue? Do i need to upload my complete APP?  This is not possible for me because the project is a new Development for the market.

Comment: You can also send any code to help@realm.io if you want to keep it private. If you cannot reproduce the problem in a new project, there is not much we can do without the original code though.

Comment: Ok, I will talk about that  with my team tomorrow. Thx.

Comment: I think it is the same issue with https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2484 if you are using windows.

Comment: @beeender you are my hero. This is exactly the problem. My  App has to modules. If I put the    apply plugin: 'realm-android'  on both gradlefiles it doesn't work. If i remove one of the     apply plugin: 'realm-android' lines it works.

Comment: @Christian Melchior  Can you look to fix this issue?
I think I am not the only one who has that problem. [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2484)

Comment: @Mike There is a fix already. You can see in the PR mentioned in http://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2484. We will release it soon. :)

Comment: So I have to wait for the new release?

Comment: 0.88.3 was just released with a fix for this.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try it tomorrow